# Missing `wcstok_s`

Tags: visual-studio, vcredist

I've just installed OpenShot to edit some videos, but sadly I'm stopped by the error `Entry point wcstok_s not found in msvcrt.dll`. I've installed Visual C++ redistributable 2010, 2012, 2015 and 2015, did not change anything. I can inspect all the `msvcrt.dll` I have in my system and none of them contains the function.

Do you know which version of the redistributable I need?

Comment: Not finding the function is of course the problem.  Open source projects don't use the Visual C++ redist.  Your Windows version is too old, if you don't want to update then you'll have to limp along with an older release of OpenShot.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, I¨ve tried all versions on their website. My next move is to compile from source, that should pretty much solve it, except that it will probably kill the better part of my weekend. Also, can you comment on why `Open source projects don't use the Visual C++ redist`? If they compile with VS, then they use it, no?